# What is wrong with my coolant reservoir tank

Tags: honda, civic, coolant-reservoir

So the coolant reservoir tank seems to boil after around 15 minutes of the car running and spills some coolant too. What can be the issue and will it be expensive?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this the cap you speak about?

Comment: Suggest you add the images to your question as that will make people understand it is your tank and not just an example image.

Comment: That does not look like the cap for the pressurized cooling system. That may be the cap for the windscreen washer fluid...

Comment: I take it your Civic is a 2001-2005 model year? Is it an EX, DX, LX, or ? And you stated it boils from the white bottle, yet you've recently changed the metal cap to try and fix the issue?

Comment: Yes any idea why?

Comment: Could it be that I have a blown head gasket?

Comment: Very likely. You didn't answer my question of which model it is?

Comment: "Could it be that I have a blown head gasket?" Most likely you have, this is one of the symptoms of that, coolant percolating back into the overflow reservoir.

Comment: It is a 2001 lx

Comment: Is it expensive to repair

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem recently on a 02 Honda Civic LX. Boiling coolant, overfilled overflow tank, overheating. The problem was caused by a warped cylinder head that was allowing exhaust gas to leak into the cooling system. I pulled the head, had it shaved. A LOT OF WORK! Have fun!   :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the system  may not be pressurizing -  there are a couple of things to check:

1) is the cap tight? Or is it broken, as some are designed to allow air to enter if the system goes below atmospheric pressure

2) are there any leaks evident?

Edit the cap may look something like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I close the cap right after I check it, how do I verify that maybe the cap needs to be changed?

Comment: When you say "close" is it properly tight? Does it have the seal inside? Is the seal in good condition ie no cracks, splits or chunks missing?

Comment: Yes I meant I close it tight. And was that the cap you were speaking about? I recently changed the other cap

Comment: The one I just addded is the one I just changed

Comment: The one with the white cap is the one that boils.